# Can not display tooltip when mouse is over text on PDF

Tags: pdf, xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I need some way to have like a tooltip when the mouse is over text. I mean, something like `<block>Some text</block>` and when the mouse is over "Some text" y need to display a tooltip, just like an HTML link that when the mouse is over it, a tooltip with the value of the title attribute is displayed.
I've searched so much and could not find the answer to my problem.

Comment: I have never encountered anything like a tooltip in XSL-FO and I am tempted to say that's impossible. That is, with XSL-FO. How about producing [PDF with LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155518/tooltip-that-works-with-all-pdf-readers)? Also see [this old thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.text.xml.fop.user/26568).

Comment: Thanks for your time! But i have no choise, i need to use XSL-FO

Comment: After some more minutes of investigation, I still do not think anything like that is implemented. But it depends on your XSL-FO renderer. Do you use FOP or a commercial product?

Comment: I believe only RenderX XEP supports tooltip annotations in an XSL FO extension.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations in PDF are not part of the XSL FO Specification. The only product I am aware of that supports such things is RenderX's XEP engine. You can review the documentation on this feature here:

http://www.renderx.com/reference.html#PDF%20Note%20Annotations

One would use:

```
 <fo:block>Note here<rx:pdf-comment content="This is the text of a popup comment"/> and some text after</fo:block>
```

rx:pdf-comment has additional attributes to set the title of the annotation, the color of the annotation and the opacity it displays with. You can also change the icon used in the PDF.